# Entity Framework 6 Code First - Relationship between 2 tables using an existing DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am having some hard time to get data from Detail table, but I can get data back from the DetailKey table.  This is what I have done so far and thank you for any help.

```
public class DetailKey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string System { get; set; }
    public string KeyValue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DetailId { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public Detail()
    {
        this.DetailKeys = new HashSet<DetailKey>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTimeOffset CreatedDatetime { get; set; }
    public System.DateTimeOffset UpdatedDatetime { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DetailKey> DetailKeys { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
     public MyDbContext() :base("name=dbConnectionString"){}

     public DbSet<Detail> Details {get; set;}
     public DbSet<DetailKey> DetailKeys {get; set;}
}

using(var db = new MyDbContext())
{
     db.Details; // I get no result.
     db.DetailKeys; // I get an exception System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecution.Exception
{
```

Comment: What EF version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 6

Comment: I've tried your model in my EF6.1.3 and it works. What is the exception **message** you are getting?

Comment: I get this one: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Comment: Also, I am using an existing database.

Comment: what is the InnerException of your EntityCommandExecutionException? I'm suspecting the model does not match, which would explain the empty result on details. However, the standard initializer should be DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges, which would be weird if it were to throw an EntityCommandExecutionException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that why there is no related **Detail** class in **DetailKey** class;

You should add **foreign key** to **DetailKey** table

Comment: Ok, but why I don't get database back from detail table? PLEASE  see my update.

Comment: Your tables looks like **Detail** and **DetailKey** has one to many relationship. Detail has always DetailKey list. If you want to one to one relationship You should check tables again and update edmx @Doro

Comment: Yes that is correct about the one to many relationship, but right now I am not getting data from one table, actually I get an exception.

Comment: Tell me exception please @Doro

Comment: Be sure, Tables and entity classes must be same. Try to update edmx and try again @Doro

Comment: I am using Code First = there is not .edmx

Comment: Sorry My bad @Doro

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the Detail table is that there is some unmatched field.  However, I come around this problem by using ADO.NET Entity Data Model and then select Code First from database. Now I get all my entities and all the data back. I cannot believe I had spend so much time on this.